# Entry field not showing when in tab Notebook Tkinter and Pack

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, tkinter-entry

I have this code:

```
    item_box_fn = ttk.Frame(tab1)
    item_box_fn.pack()

    item_label_fn = ttk.Label(item_box_fn, text="Forename", width=100)
    item_label_fn.pack(side=LEFT)

    item_field_fn = ttk.Entry(item_box_fn, width=250)
    item_field_fn.pack(side=LEFT)
```

The tabs work as expected, and everything else is as it should be.

The label shows up correctly, but the Entry does not.

If I put the Entry outside of the tab it shows, just not in the tab, or any child frames.

What might I be doing wrong?

Edit:
This is the code including all frames:

```
    self.container_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
    self.container_frame.pack()

    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self.container_frame, width=700, height=400)

    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab4 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

    tabControl.add(tab1, text='Staff Details')

    self.cols_names = ['Forename', 'Surname', 'email', 'Phone']
    self.cols = ['forename', 'surname', 'email', 'phone']
    self.col_widths = [180, 180, 150, 150]

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(tab1, selectmode='browse', columns=self.cols, show='headings')
    self.tree["displaycolumns"] = (0, 1, 2, 3)

    i = 0
    for x in self.cols:
        self.tree.heading(i, text=self.cols_names[i])
        self.tree.column(i, width=self.col_widths[i])
        i = i + 1
    self.tree.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

    self.tutor_list = global_list_tutors()
    print(self.tutor_list)

    inc = 0
    for data in self.tutor_list:
        self.tree.insert("", iid=inc, index='end', text=data[0], values=(data[1], data[2], data[3]))
        inc = inc +1

    tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both", padx=10, pady=5)

    item_box_fn = ttk.Frame(tab1)
    item_box_fn.pack()

    item_label_fn = ttk.Label(item_box_fn, text="Forename", width=100)
    item_label_fn.pack(side=LEFT)

    item_field_fn = ttk.Entry(item_box_fn, width=100)
    item_field_fn.pack(side=LEFT)

    tabControl.add(tab2, text='Finance & Charges')
    tabControl.add(tab3, text='Institution Details')
    tabControl.add(tab4, text='General')
```

Further Edit:

If I remove the side=LEFT from the label, the Entry is displayed.

Comment: The width option of label and entry is in characters, not pixels.  So the entry box is pushed out of the viewable area of the window.

Comment: Yes! That is the issue. Thanks. I just realised this when playing around with the code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can run. You've posted unrunnable code.

Answer (score 1):

> Entry field not showing when in tab Notebook Tkinter and Pack

Edit: add keyword `width` in `Lablel`

It is because you are setting keyword `width` to over 100 and that is why the `Entry` are out of offset. And you are setting `width=250`

To reduce `width` setting.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Notebook")
root.geometry('200x100')
 
tab1 = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

item_box_fn = ttk.Frame(tab1) 

tab1.add(item_box_fn, text='tab1')

item_label_fn = ttk.Label(item_box_fn, text="Forename", width=10, background='red')
item_label_fn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.W) 

item_field_fn = ttk.Entry(item_box_fn, width=20)
item_field_fn.focus_set()
item_field_fn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.W, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That is interesting. I didn't know that. It still doesn't show up, even if I completely remove the width. I will post the whole section of my code. It has to be something else that is causing this, because if I create a clean example (as you did) and run it separately, it doesn't exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: You can set width to whatever depending on window size.   item_label_fn = ttk.Label(item_box_fn, text="Forename", width=20, I forgotten to add width in Label